# Node.js - file upload with multer and attach file to email using Sendgrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, multer

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('attachment');

// sgMail intialization

exports.sendMail = (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, err => {
    if(!err) {
      const fileInfo = req.file;
      const msg = {
        to: 'toemail@gmail.com',
        from: 'fromemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Welcome!',
        html: `<p>Some text description</p>`,
        attachments: [
          {
            content: fileInfo.buffer.toString('base64'),
            filename: fileInfo.key,
            type: 'text/plain',
            disposition: 'attachment'
          },
        ],
      };
      sgMail.send(msg)
        .then(() => {
          res.json({data: 'success});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.json({data: 'error'});
        });
     }
  });
}
```

Error: 'fileInfo' is undefined and hence gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
```

Queries:

1. Content-Type header is not set. If required, what should be the value?
2. Is something wrong with the multer implementation

Answer (score 0):

`const fileInfo = req.file;` should be `const fileInfo = req.files;` (plural).

Output the contents of `req.files` as you'll most likely have to target an array index or key name of your upload.